# Is there any way to get session data on Model boot method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have some trouble in getting the session data on the boot method in Eloquent model,

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('sessionDataQuery', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            // I cant get any session data here
            $builder->where('belong_admin_id', app()->session->get('admin')->id);
        });
    }

    // However,I can use this method to set query condition manually, but it need to be called everytime.
    public function scopeSetAdmin($query)
    {
        $admin = app()->session->get('admin');
        $query->where('belong_admin_id', $admin->id);
    }
}
```

I want to set the query condition just once which is convenient if I set it in the boot method, so I dont need to set it everytime when I use the model, but it seems cant any get session data in model boot.I also tried `__construct` method but didnt work either. Is there any solutions or is there a better way to do it.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the facade instead:

```
use Session;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('sessionDataQuery', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('belong_admin_id', Session::get('admin')->id);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Since facade worked, I think the helper method would work as well; could you please confirm it?

```
session()->get('admin')->id
```

Comment: I think the helper method works as well. Could you please confirm it?